# How to properly use types with flow and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, flowtype

How to make following use case with Flow and nodejs?

Requirements:

1. have Type definitions in a separate file(s), for now lets say all in `Types.js`
2. to use it inside another file/module:

   ```
   const MyRequiredType = require('Types').MyRequiredType;
   const methodWithInputTypeCheck = function(request: MyRequiredType){ }
   ```

Tried to use [flow-aliases](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/aliases/), but this seems to work only when have the declaration in the same file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it seems that at the end it is far more simpler.

Looks like we can use std. classes:

1./ Types.js

```
// @flow
const Types =
{
    SomethingWithUserRequest: class MyClass {
        userId: string;   //thanks to Babel
        userNick: string;
    }
};

module.exports = Types;
```

2./ SomeModule.js:

```
const SomethingWithUserRequest = require('../service/Dto/Types').SomethingWithUserRequest;

const TestFacade =
{
    testFlow: function(
        request: SomethingWithUserRequest
    ) {
        console.log('userId', request.userId);
    }
};

module.exports = TestFacade;
```

Only the IDE is still confused and does not hint in this way.